# How to release memory during vba ie navigation

Tags: ms-access, vba

Suggestion required regarding below mentioned code memory usage as it is taking huge memory during processing.Plese guide how to release momory after each url processing so that there is no ie navigation error.Code is given below.

```vb
Dim RowCount As String
stDB = "Data Source=C:\off_Ch.accdb"
stProvider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
With cn
    .ConnectionString = stDB
    .Provider = stProvider
    .Open
    Set ie = Nothing
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    RowCount = DMin("[id]", "url", "[Flag] = False")
    maxid = DMax("[id]", "url", "[Flag] = False")
    Do While RowCount <> ""
        Set HTML = Nothing
        url = DLookup("[url]", "url", "ID = " & ([RowCount]))
        priceval = ""
        ie.navigate url
        On Error Resume Next
        Do While ie.ReadyState <> 4 Or _
                ie.Busy = True
            On Error Resume Next
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Set HTML = ie.Document
        Set my_data = HTML.getElementById("breadcrumbResultArea")
        selrem = my_data.innerText
        stSQL = "INSERT INTO off (seller_identity, url,id) " & _
            "Values ('" & selrem & "','" & url & "','" & RowCount & "')"
        cn.Execute stSQL
        If RowCount > maxid Then Exit Do
        RowCount = RowCount + 1
        On Error Resume Next
        ie.Refresh2
    Loop
    Set ie = Nothing
    Set HTML = Nothing
End With
ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Error Code is given below

Error more detail is given below.

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:    APPCRASH
  Application Name:    IEXPLORE.EXE
  Application Version:    11.0.9600.18124
  Application Timestamp:    5641278d
  Fault Module Name:    jscript9.dll
  Fault Module Version:    11.0.9600.18124
  Fault Module Timestamp:    56413027
  Exception Code:    c0000005
  Exception Offset:    0007772c
  OS Version:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1:    25c4
  Additional Information 2:    25c494805ba8021c831f7da5514f4335
  Additional Information 3:    3eda
  Additional Information 4:    3eda1b263b257f9fa235fc5fb2929be2

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Comment: If anyone have some idea regarding memory release then please share feedback..thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`ie.Refresh2` is superfluous - the next action is to navigate to a new URL.

You should get rid of all those `On Error Resume Next` statements - they mask errors. E.g. `ie.Quit` won't work because `ie` has been set Nothing before.

`Set my_data = Nothing` after reading its innerText may help, but should not be necessary.

Comment: So ie.Refresh2 is creating problem.I use on error resume next because i am facing error i.e Internet Explorer has stopped working.I update error code.